# change the format of matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

say I have the following data without a header

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 1 |
| a | b | 1 |
| a | c | 1 |
| b | a | 2 |
| b | b | 2 |
| b | c | 2 |
| c | a | 3 |
| c | b | 3 |
| c | c | 3 |

I want to get the data in the following format

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| c | 3 | 3 | 3 |

I have tried the following but didn't work out

```
df= df.pivot_table("2","1")
```

It didn't work for me but it is either wrong or it doesn't work as the df has no header. Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: If there is no defined header, then it is likely integers.

Comment: `df.pivot(columns=['1'], index=['0'], values='2').rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: I am getting an error when reading the index, it can't read the index 0 for some reason. KeyError: '0'

Comment: @mozway I didn't define the headers on purpose. It is a specific type of matrix, the so-called OD matrix.

Comment: @Kimchi try removing the quotes from the column names, e.g. -> `columns=[1], index=[0], values=2`

Comment: @Kimchi a dataframe necessarily has column names, what is the output of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: it is solved now, I made a header for the data frame and used @user17242583 line there but without the index as follows:
df.pivot( columns='a', values='2').rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)